What is the format to wrap children in antd TreeSelect?
I have tried wrapping the treeData of TreeSelect within the component instead of passing it as props.
<TreeSelect
      style={{ width: '120px' }}
      defaultValue={CurrentUser()}
      showCheckedStrategy={TreeSelect.SHOW_CHILD}
      maxTagCount="responsive"
      onChange={(e) => {
       setUser(e)
      }}
      treeCheckable
      value={quarter}
      placeholder="Select Quarter"
     >
      <>
       {selectedUsers.length > 0 ? (
        <span
         onClick={() => setUsers([])}
         style={{
          display: 'inline-block',
          color: '#286FBE',
          cursor: 'pointer',
         }}
        >
         Unselect all
        </span>
       ) : (
        <span
         onClick={() => setUsers(allUsers)}
         style={{
          display: 'inline-block',
          color: '#286FBE',
          cursor: 'pointer',
         }}
        >
         Select all
        </span>
       )}
       {UsersData?.map((i) => (
        <Select.Option key={i?.value} value={i?.value}>
         {i?.label}
        </Select.Option>
       ))}
      </>
     </TreeSelect>

I am not getting the desired output. Following this way because of pagination. I have to fetch paginated users data.

I got the solution. Wrap the children in the TreeNode component with props title, value, disabled, and children.
